# Ref request: A graph G contains H as a minor iff it contains one of finitely many graphs as a topological minor

Tags: graph-minors, reference-request, graph-theory

For definitions of graph minors and topological minors, see wikipedia's article on [graph minors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_minor).

Theorem: For every graph H, there is a finite set of graphs, say S(H), such that G contains H as a minor if and only if G contains some graph from S(H) as a topological minor.

Can anyone point me to a paper/book where this is proved? (I know how to prove it, I just want a reference to cite.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hello !!! You will find this theorem as results 2.2 and 2.3 in Graph minors VIII : A Kuratowski theorem for general surfaces.

Nathann

Comment: The paper Nathann refers to is online at http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0095-8956(90)90121-F

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what I needed.